# Prove that difference in area of circumcircle and polygon is greater than the difference in area of polygon and incircle.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles, area

The problem can be equivalently stated as

**PROBLEM :** A convex $n$ sided polygon has a circumcircle and an inscribed circle, its area is $B$, and the areas of circumcircle and inscribed circle are $A$ and $C$ respectively. Prove that $2B < A+C$.

I think this problem is very difficult. This is my attempt for special case of polygons i.e *Regular polygons*.

*Naming of parameters :*

$R$ be the radius of circumcircle of the polygon.
$r$ be inradius of the polygon.
$n$ be the number of sides of polygon.
$\theta$ = $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ = angle subtended by a side of polygon at centre.
$a$ be the length of side of polygon.

*Relations between $R,r,a,\theta$* :

$R^2 = \frac{a^2}{4} + r^2$, $a = 2R*sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$ and $r = R*cos(\frac{\theta}{2})$

We need to prove $2B < A+C$
$\Leftrightarrow \frac{2sin(\theta)}{3+cos(\theta)} < \frac{\pi}{n}$

This can be verified by showing that, inequality is true for $n = 3 $ and LHS decreases faster than RHS.

The method I used for regular polygons isn't applicable to all. There is too much freedom and ambiguity. But I don't have any idea to tackle generalized polygon. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually simple. If the perimeter of your convex shape is $P$, then your inequality is equivalent to:
$$\pi(r^2+R^2) > Pr,$$
where $R$ and $r$ are the circumradius and inradius, respectively. A trivial upper bound on the perimeter is:
$$P < 2\pi R$$
where the latter is the length of the circumcircle. But now a simple AM-GM finishes the problem:

$$Pr < 2\pi Rr < \pi(r^2+R^2)$$

Comment: ........No words to say. Beautiful proof. I unnecessarily overcomplicated the problem. How stupid of me.. Thanks @dezdichado

Comment: @MathematicalCuriosity no need to call yourself stupid. This is pure experience - I did probably thousands of Euclidean geometry problems in secondary school for math contest and so I happen to know basic ideas, techniques that are applicable in most cases.